# Error when I add QtWebKit in my Qt Program (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwebkit

if i use

```
#include <QtWebKit>
```

and => "QT += webkit" or "QT += webkitwidgets" in file.pro

```
-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
```

i also run the qmake but still doesn't work

Ubuntu : 13.04

Qt     : Based on Qt 5.0.1 (64 bit)

in this [web site](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) i found the realese of WebKit but I'm not able to download it

so how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `QT += webkit`, but ...

You also need to make sure you have the webkit libraries installed. Go to the following website to grab the latest QtWebKit library version: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Alternatively, you can also go to this page to get older versions if you really need 5.0.X:

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/

Slightly off-topic, so pardon me: but you should not include the what QtWebKit module. That may cause some not insignificant overhead.